# What would be a good translation of "to go well with"?

Tags: traducción, modismos

How could one translate the expression "to go well with" in Spanish?

**For example:**

> Tequila shots go well with strawberry ice cream.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Spain se use:

> "pegar con" -> Ese gorro no te pega con la blusa.
>   "ir bien con" -> Ese vino va bien con el solomillo de ternera.

For food and drinks I'd use the second option better, which is a literal translation of "to go well".

Comment: "Combina bien" is also a choice.

Comment: @kelmer: Yes. It sounds a bit less coloquial, though.

Comment: Yet another one! (which I use specially with drinks): "mezcla bien" (literally, "mixes well")

Answer (score 5):

And in the context of colors one would say (in the sense of matching) "hacer juego con ..."; e.g. "Esta blausa hace juego con mis zapatos."